# Error setting project google cloud with bash

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform

this command run perfectly If i execute from my google cloud sdk shell on windows but if I put this command in a bash script this command fail!! Some idea?

```
gcloud config set project my-project-id
```

the error is:

```
D:\temp\bash test.sh

] is not a valid project ID.he project property must be set to a valid project ID, [bdtg-shared-infra-prod
```

Comment: If you run `bash -x yourscript`, what exactly does the line it shows logging its gcloud invocation contain? Please make sure you're providing us with a [mcve] that generates that same logged line -- otherwise, you aren't giving us enough to truly reproduce the problem.

Comment: Actually, given that the string jumped back to the beginning of the line, what you have is almost certainly a CRLF DOS-style newline.

Comment: You can use VI to change the EOL character (which is your problem). `:set fileformat=unix`

Comment: Thanks a lot charles Duffy, I write again the command with nano editor and its executed successfully. This was a dum error